# cURL not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, curl

I am doing a custom SMS gateway integration with Laravel. I used curl for that. Curl is already enabled in my localhost(XAMPP, ubuntu) and I can use curl in simple PHP. But when I try to call `curl_init()` in laravel leads to an error `FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 311:
Call to undefined function Ixudra\Curl\curl_init()`. When I use `var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));` , I got `bool(false)`. How can I use curl in Larvel

Comment: are you using `wamp`,`xamp` or ?_ go to `php.ini` and check whether you have enabled the `curl` by searching for `;extension=php_curl.dll`

Comment: are you sure the library you are using `Ixudra\Curl`, has such method `curl_init`?

Comment: why the **** are you using xampp on ubuntu? there's no auto update ,and you lose all the benefits of the ubuntu security team patches and you'll have to roll your own unattended-upgrades and trust the xampp team to provide security patches in a timely manner... which they don't (usually takes several months between releases, that includes security patches)

Comment: I can use curl request in pure PHP code. But  can not use that code in laravel\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `php.ini` for the `extension=php_curl.dll` and make sure it is enabled. If not,enable it and restart xampp. Check the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) here for a sample request.